# common.h: No such file or directory (Ubuntu gcc)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

When I was trying to compile a C program like this:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 #include <stdlib.h>
3 #include <sys/time.h>
4 #include <assert.h>
5 #include "common.h"
6
7 int
8 main(int argc, char *argv[])
9 {
10 if (argc != 2) {
11 fprintf(stderr, "usage: cpu <string>\n");
12 exit(1);
13 }
14 char *str = argv[1];
15 while (1) {
16 Spin(1);
17 printf("%s\n", str);
18 }
19 return 0;
20 }
```

and I received a error

```
CPU.c:5:19: fatal error: common.h: No such file or directory
```

I have update my gcc compiler, so I cannot figure out why there is a miss of  "Common.h"

Comment: It is example from operating system books. It doesn't inlcude common.h. Instead of common.h include: `#include <unistd.h>`, and instead of Spin use `sleep` funcion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`common.h` is not part of the C standard library, it's a third-party header file (is it yours?).

You need to put `common.h` into the same directory as the file the code of which you posted, otherwise the compiler won't be able to find it without some help.

By "some help" I mean include paths. When you include a file the compiler will search for it in pre-defined locations it knows about, plus the current directory (the directory of the file it's compiling right now) if you're using quotes (`"somefile.h"`) instead of angle brackets (`<somefile.h>`).

So you either need to put the header in one of those places or define a new one (a custom include directory) with the `-I` flag in gcc like so:

```
gcc -Ipath/to/your/dir/here myfile.c
```